# Posting parameters in Alamofire

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire, postman

I'm trying to make a Post request to my API through Alamofire that I am able to make in Postman.

In Postman my request looks like this:

[image]

This will give a Success response.

In my app I try to do this as well through the following function:

```
func postUserInterests(interests: [Interest], user: User, completionHandler: (([AnyObject]?, ErrorType?) -> Void)) {
    let urlString = Constant.apiUrl().stringByAppendingFormat(Constant.apiPostUserInterests, String(user.userID!))

    var selectedInterests = [Int]()

    for interest in interests {
        if (interest.selected){
            selectedInterests.append(interest.id!)
        }
    }

//        let parameters = ["interest_ids": selectedInterests]
    let parameters = ["interest_ids": [1,2,3]]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parameters, headers: self.header).validate().responseJSON { request, response, result in
        switch (result) {
        case .Success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let jsonArray = json["data"].rawString()
            print(jsonArray)
            if let items:Array<Item> = Mapper<Item>().mapArray(jsonArray) {
                completionHandler(items, nil)
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil, ApiError.ParseError);
            }
        case .Failure(let data, let error):
            print(data)
            print(error)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This will however shoot into the .Failure response printing the following:

```
Optional(<7b226d65 73736167 65223a22 6d697373 696e6720 70617261 6d657465 72732122 7d>)

Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was unacceptable: 422" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status code was unacceptable: 422}
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to post a simple array of Integers to my backend

Comment: leave validate() for now, what exactly code in postman do you see in response?

Answer (score 0):

Was missing the 'encoding: .JSON' part:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parameters, headers: self.header, encoding: .JSON)
```